# On the seeking for the pairs of identical files

Tags: bash, file, nested-loops

I need to seek 2 dirs for the pair of files having identical tittles (but not the extensions!) and merge their titles within some new command.

## first how to print only name of the files

1)Typically I use the following command within the for loop to select the full name of the file which is looped

```
for file in ./files/* do;
 title=$(base name "file")
 print title
done
```

What should I change in the above script to print as the title of only name of the file but not its extension?

2) how its possible to add some condition to check whether two files has the same names performing double looping over them e,g

```
# counter for the detected equal files
i=0
for file in ./files1/* do;
 title=$(base name "file") #change it to avoid extension within the title
 for file2 in ./files2/* do;
 title2=$(basename "file2") #change it to avoid extension within the title2
 if title1==title2
 echo $title1 and $title2 'has been found!'
 i=i+1
```

done

Thanks for help!
Gleb

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

You could start by fixing the syntax errors in your script, such as `do` followed by `;` when it should be the other way round.

Then, the shell has operators to remove sub-strings from the start (`##`, `#`) and end (`%%`, `%`) in a variable. Here's how to list files without extensions, i.e. removing the shortest part that matches the glob `.*` from the right:

```
 for file in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "${file%.*}"
 done
```

Read your shell manual to find out about these operators. It will pay for itself many times over in your programming career :-)

Do not believe anyone telling you to use ugly and expensive piping and forking with basename, cut, awk and such. That's all overkill.

On the other hand, maybe there's a better way to achieve your goal. Suppose you have files like this:

```
$ find files1 files2
files1
files1/file1.x
files1/file3.z
files1/file2.y
files2
files2/file1.x
files2/file4.b
files2/file3.a
```

Now create two lists of file names, extensions stripped:

```
ls files1 | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort > f1
ls files2 | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sort > f2
```

The `comm` utility tests for lines common in two files:

```
 $ comm f1 f2
                file1
 file2
                file3
        file4
```

The first column lists lines only in `f1`, the second only in `f2` and the third common to both. Using the `-1` `-2` `-3` options you can suppress unwanted columns. If you need to count only the common files (third column) , run

```
$ comm -1 -2 f1 f2 | wc -l
      2
```

Comment: thanks so much for the idea! and will it possible to associate title of the file made by your pattern with some new variable associated exactly with the file in folder (like what basename  exactly do)? I need to match names on next step with the files having identical names but different extensions from another dir to find pairs with identical tittles. Could you show some example how it could be done using my idea with nested loop? In fact I'm not a programmer at all just use shell to facilitate analysis of some scientific data :) Thanks!

Comment: @user3470313 Would this slightly different idea provide the same answer: 1) For each of the two directories, create a sorted file list without extensions. 2) Compare the file lists, telling for each file "Is only in list 1", "Is only in list 2", "Is in both lists"?

Comment: It sound good but I don't know how to make lists in shell only did it in the python :) So I will thankful for the example of the script which will: 1) make new variable for each looping file associated with its name w/o extension or alternatively put the name to the list  2) compare elements from two lists. Thanks! Gleb

Comment: @user3470313 Okay, I've spelled it out. Does that solve your problem?